Erro "ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED" ao executar projeto TypeScript com `ts-node` e ESM
Estou tentando executar um projeto TypeScript usando ts-node com módulos ESM, mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:
Error: Package subpath './register/esm' is not defined by "exports" in /path/to/node_modules/ts-node/package.json
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:296:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:643:9)
    ...
    code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'

Comando utilizado:
npx ts-node -r ts-node/register/esm app.ts

Ambiente:

Node.js: v22.11.0
ts-node: v10.9.2
TypeScript: v5.7.2
Sistema Operacional: Debian 12 (nativo e WSL)

O que já tentei:

Alterar o comando para:
npx ts-node --loader ts-node/esm app.ts

Resultado:
Unknown or unexpected option: --loader


Executar com tsconfig-paths:
npx ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register app.ts

Resultado: O mesmo erro persistiu.

Atualizei ts-node e TypeScript para as versões mais recentes, mas o problema continua.

Revisei o tsconfig.json, configurando "module": "ESNext" e "moduleResolution": "node".


Trecho do tsconfig.json relevante:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

Pergunta:
Como executar ts-node com suporte a ESM corretamente? Preciso ajustar alguma configuração adicional no tsconfig.json ou há um comando alternativo que funcione?
Agradeço qualquer sugestão ou orientação!
